# htaccess for simple PHP API

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am completly new to htaccess, never have to do it on my own. But its time.

I have a simple PHP API, so I need redirect all urls to index.php (PHP will handle routing), so

```
localhost/api/user
localhost/api/post
localhost/api/whatever
```

Goes to

```
localhost/index.php
```

This is quite simple i gues?

```
RewriteRule (.*) /api/index.php
```

But than I need one more thing and thats, when the last sequence of url is number like:

```
localhost/api/user/142
localhost/api/post/675
localhost/api/whatever/2136912
```

It Should Go to
Goes to

```
localhost/index.php?id=GIVEN_NUMBER
```

Is there even a way to do that, or should I start work on PHP solutiuon?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a rule like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L]
```

Then on index.php parse the requested URL and take your action.